# Mostrar descripción en Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, html5, fullcalendar

Tengo un problema y es que no me muestra la descripción de los eventos, está conectado a google, me muestra los eventos, con las horas marcadas pero no la descripción alguna ayuda? Solo tengo eso de código, El bootstrapcdn lo tengo comentado por problemas de versión.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            Events
        </title>    
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fullcalendar.css">
         </head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fullcalendar.min.css">


            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="moment.min.js"></script>
            <script src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
            <script src="gcal.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        header: {
                        left: 'prev,next, today',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek, agendaDay, list'
                    },
                        editable: true,
                        googleCalendarApiKey:'*************************',
                        events:{
                            googleCalendarId:'************************',
                        }

                    });
                });
            </script>
        <body>
            <div id="loading"></div>
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Adjunto imagen :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto

```
title: v.subject /*Asi es como te lo podra mostrar*/
```

Comment: Lo he insertado tanto debajo de events:{ } como encima y no me muestra nada, lo estoy insertando mal? Acabo de adjuntar una foto de lo que me muestra por pantalla

Comment: Dentro de events:{ } colocale title: '' prueba esto a ver

Comment: events:
     {
      title:'My Event',
      googleCalendarId:'*************',
      className: 'gcal-event'
     } No funciona

Comment: mira la respuesta, que la modifique nada mas tienes que colocar lo que te indique

Comment: Disculpa, es que no tengo variables para asignar, he visto que no recibo el asunto, pero si un id y la api de google calendar tiene un get que con el id sacas el asunto, voy a ver si puedo sacarlo

Comment: Eso es lo que tienes que hacer poner id del asunto y tiene que funcionar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69503/discussion-between-ing-jose-valera-and-windstone).